# Select element containing other element with attribute value in E4X

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, e4x

```
<root>
 <function name="lala">
  <metadata name="foo" />
 </function>
 <function />
 ...
</root>
```

In the XML tree above, how can I select the one (or first) `function` containing a `metadata` with `@name` being "foo" in an ActionScript 3 E4X expression?

What I've tried, but doesn't work, is:

```
// should trace "lala", traces "" 
trace(root.function.(contains(metadata.(@name=="foo"))).@name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it's a bit ugly

```
trace(XML(root.function.metadata.(@name=="foo")).parent().@name);
```